# Smooth movement java

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm working on some AI stuff in Java. When an entity moves towards a point, the movement does not look natural. If its starting point and target are not equal X and Y distances away from each other, the movement looks like this: [image: Unnatural movement]

What I want it to look move like is this: [image: Smoother movement]

Currently, movement is done like so:

```
        int tX = target.x;
        int tY = target.y;

        if(tX> oX){
            getOwner().addX(getOwner().getMoveSpeed());
        }

        if(tX < oX){
            getOwner().addX(-getOwner().getMoveSpeed());
        }

        if(tY> oY){
            getOwner().addY(getOwner().getMoveSpeed());
        }

        if(tY< oY){
            getOwner().addY(-getOwner().getMoveSpeed());
        }
```

I'm guessing that there is a much better method for handling movement than this.

So what I want to know is probably how to work out the angle I need to move along, and then the x and y velocitys needed to do so.

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: If you have the two points, you can simply calculate the line connecting them, then scale your x or y movement accordingly (ie, for every +x, add +1.2y, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to scale the x and y speeds according to the total distance to be traveled in each direction.

It will help to do the calculations in floating point and round to an `int` only when you need to assign a position.

```
int tX = target.x;
int tY = target.y;
float speed = getOwner.getMoveSpeed();
float dX = tX - oX;
float dY = tY - oY;
float dist = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
float sX = speed * dX / dist;
float sY = speed * dY / dist;

getOwner().addX((int) (sX + 0.5));
getOwner().addY((int) (sY + 0.5));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the process of drawing a line between two points.

There are relatively simple integer-only algorithms, such as [Bresenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) that may help.